# Calling simple asmx webservice method on HTML page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, asmx

I would like to ask you for help to solve my problem with calling ASP.NET webservice method on HTML page. The code is extremally simple, but is generally not working. Generally, because I found one browser - IE 11, on witch it works fine. On every other browser the webservice reponse is empty (status property of XMLHttpRequest object returns 0 instead of 200). It is interesting that if I put directly the method address (http://www.rpdp.hostingasp.pl/RPDPWebService.asmx/HelloWorld) to the URL bar of any browser the result is correct: <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>. Conclusion - webservice works good, but I cannot call it's methods correctly in JS code.
I've read multiple discussions on this matter and suppose that the problem is related to the security issues and cross-orgin resource sharing. All this concidered, I have tried many tips, but with no success. I am very new to this matter and would be very grateful if anyone could tell what am I to change in the code below to make it work on every browser.

Kind regards,

Piotrek

P.S. I publish my webservice on external hosting ASP.NET webserver so I cannot change it's (server) settings.

ASP.NET webservice:

```
namespace RPDP
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class RPDPWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

In web.config.xml file I have added following tags (first in , second - in ):

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>

<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

HTML page, on which I call my webservice method:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <script>
    function go()
    {   
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", "http://www.rpdp.hostingasp.pl/RPDPWebService.asmx/HelloWorld", true);

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( req.readyState == 4) {
                if ( req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300 ||req.status == 304 ) {      
                    var returnData = req.responseText;
                    alert('Success! Returned data: ' + returnData);
                } else {
                    alert("Error; request.status = " + req.status);
                }
                req = null;
            };
        }

        req.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="go();"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following blogpost: https://zqzhang.github.io/blog/2016/04/18/why-use-onload-in-cross-domain-ajax.html

It suggests the usage of the `onload` insted of the `onreadystatechange` when performing a cross-domain Ajax request.

## The issue was that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` had been defined twice.

Comment: Thank you Örvar for your answer. Unfortunatelly result is the same - OK in IE 11, empty in other browsers :(.

 function go()
 { 
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "http://www.rpdp.hostingasp.pl/RPDPWebService.asmx/HelloWorld", true);
  
  req.onload = function(){
     var returnData = req.responseText;
     alert('Success! Returned data: ' + returnData);
    req = null;
  }
  
  req.send(null);
 }

Comment: What errors can you see in the chrome developer tool console?

Comment: Can it be that you are setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` more than once? You could try to remove `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` from your webconfig.

Comment: I don't use it, but when I run Fiddler, I see correct result(!):

GET http://www.rpdp.hostingasp.pl/RPDPWebService.asmx/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: www.rpdp.hostingasp.pl
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>

So the webservice returns data to browser but browser just cannot display it. Or - maybe - I have to have localhost running and index.html file in the path?

Comment: Bingo! Thank you Örvar very, very much! The reason was in setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin two times. I excluded it from web.config and result on Chrome and FireFox is OK! Once more thank you very much!

Comment: Thats great to hear :) I have edited my answer with the solution.